# Using TMDb c# api to pass info to TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, api, foreach

Has anyone ever worked with TMdb for C# before?
https://github.com/LordMike/TMDbLib/
 I'm using the API library to connect with my WPF app and would like to display some cast members in a `TextBlock` but every time I use it I only get one name, whereas according to the API I should be getting way more names. I'm using a `foreach` loop like this;

```
foreach (Cast cast in movie.Credits.Cast)
            {
                MovieCast = cast.Name;
            }
```

I don't know if maybe I'm doing something wrong?
Here's the full code;
**ViewModel**

```
#region Fields

        private Window mWindow;

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        public string MovieName { get; set; }

        public string MovieDescription { get; set; }

        public string MovieCast { get; set; }

        public string MovieImage { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #region Commands

        /// <summary>
        /// The command to close the window
        /// </summary>
        public ICommand CloseCommand { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The command to minimize the window
        /// </summary>
        public ICommand MinimizeCommand { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The command to maximize the window
        /// </summary>
        public ICommand MaximizeCommand { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        /// <summary>
        /// Main Constructor
        /// </summary>
        public MainWindowViewModel(Window window)
        {
            mWindow = window;

            // Window Buttons Commands
            CloseCommand = new RelayCommand(() => mWindow.Close());
            MinimizeCommand = new RelayCommand(() => mWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized);
            MaximizeCommand = new RelayCommand(() => mWindow.WindowState ^= WindowState.Maximized);

            //This is The Movie Database API Client
            TMDbClient client = new TMDbClient("c807e25e9945dcb331636165896edb32");
            Movie movie = client.GetMovieAsync("141052", MovieMethods.Credits | MovieMethods.Images).Result;

            MovieName = movie.Title;
            MovieDescription = movie.Overview;
            foreach (ImageData image in movie.Images.Backdrops)
            {
                MovieImage = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original"+image.FilePath;
            }

            foreach (Cast cast in movie.Credits.Cast)
            {
                MovieCast = cast.Name;
            }

        }
        #endregion
    }
```

**XAML portion**

```
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MovieName}" FontSize="40" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MovieDescription}" FontSize="15" FontWeight="DemiBold" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="700" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MovieCast}" FontSize="14"/>
```

Comment: even if `movie.Credits.Cast` has many items, `MovieCast` will be the last one of them. use collection, e.g. `List<string>`

Comment: Window in a View Model is not a MVVM. it should be vice-versa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

even if `movie.Credits.Cast` has many items, `MovieCast` is reassigned in a loop and will be the last one of them. use collection, e.g. `ObservableColection<string>` and display it in `ItemsControl`, or alternatively, join all items in a single string which can be shown in TextBlock:

```
MovieCast = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, movie.Credits.Cast);
```

Comment: Ok, from your solution I've used a `List<Cast>` and binded it to an `ItemsControl` and it ends up displaying a list that says "Cast" over and over again. What I need is a list of the Cast.Name

Comment: @HitmanDD, create custom ItemsControl.ItemTemplate or set ItemsControl.DisplayMemberPath="Name"

Comment: Yes, it's working, but now it shows all the items, how do I get it to show only 2 or 3?

Comment: Hello? Any answers on this?

Comment: @HitmanDD, you are asking the third question in the same post. I expected at least one "thanks" before that, and accepted checkmark, actually - the original issue was resolved with my help. I'm not about to write entire application for you like that.

Comment: You're not writing the entire app for me, this is only a single problem of a whole that I'm just having a lot of trouble with. Sorry I forgot to check mark but even if it solve my original problem shouldn't there be a little follow up?